# CustomValidator problem

Tags: asp.net, customvalidator

I have a number of ASP.NET validators on my page of various types, some of which I am  disabling depending on user selections on a page, using javascript.

```
$.each(Page_Validators, function(index, validator) 
       {
           if ($(validator).hasClass("pain")) {

               ValidatorEnable(validator, false);

        }
});
```

This seems to work and validators do not fire in all cases except any CustomValidators that I am using whenever I cannot use other validator types

```
 <asp:CheckBoxList id="BodyPartsList" runat="server" RepeatColumns = "2" 
                    Width="1023px">
                    <asp:ListItem Text = "0. Head/headaches" Value = "1"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Text = "1. Leg(s)" Value = "2"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Text = "2. Arm(s)" Value = "3"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Text = "3. Neck" Value = "4"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Text = "4. Shoulder(s)" Value = "5"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Text = "5. Low Back" Value = "6"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Text = "6. Upper Back" Value = "7"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Text = "7. Feet" Value = "8"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Text = "8. Hand(s)" Value = "9"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Text = "9. Other(Describe in &quot;Details of Plan&quot;)" Value = "10"></asp:ListItem>
                </asp:CheckBoxList>

                <asp:CustomValidator ID="PainLocationValidator" runat="server" Display="Dynamic"
                ErrorMessage="Location of pain is required." 
                ClientValidationFunction="checkPainListValidate" 
                ValidationGroup = "OnSave" EnableClientScript= "true" SetFocusOnError= "true" Width = "100%" CssClass = "pain" />



 function checkPainListValidate(sender, args) {

    args.IsValid = true;

    if ($('#<%= BodyPartsList.ClientID %> input:checked').length > 0)
        args.IsValid = true;

    else
        args.IsValid = false;

}
```

Why is this happening? Is there something else I can do to disable those as well?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some aspx-markup would be helpful, but anyway here are some ideas:

- have you debugged the javascript to see what's happening, if your validator is null or you have a type like `validatorEnable` instead of `ValidatorEnable`? Do you get any javascript errors?
- Does the CustomValidator validates on server- or on clientside, i think ValidatorEnable will only disable it on clientside
- set `EnableClientScript` to true
- If you dont specify a ControlToValidate, the CustomValidator will validate on every postback, regardless of the event that caused it
- Have you provided a `ClientValidationFunction` that gets called on clientside?
- by the way, what browser and what framework are you using, is it ASP.Net-Ajax?
- do you have tried to disable it via `document.getElementById('<%=MyValidator.ClientID %>').disabled=true;`?

I assume that you're using the wrong ID to get the validator in clientside.

I have tested your code and can not reproduce this behaviour:

This is my Javascript-function to disable all validators(edited to take your pain-class into account):

```
 function disablePainValidators() {
     if ((typeof (Page_Validators) != "undefined") && (Page_Validators != null)) {
         var i;
         for (i = 0; i < Page_Validators.length; i++) {
             if(Page_Validators[i].className=='pain')
                 ValidatorEnable(Page_Validators[i], false);
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for reply and some helpful ideas 1. I did not undestand 1st idea 2. I am validating it on a client-side so using `ClientValidationFunction, see the update 3. I do not specify `ControlToValidate since it's a checkboxlist and I get errors if I do that. 4. If you disable validator will it still validate on every postback?

Comment: @Victor: point 1 was a typo that i only have deleted partially(empty text is never validated if you don't set ValidateEmptyText to true, but that does not help you here). I thought you wanted to disable the validator, so why do you ask if it will validate on postback? Show us also the js-code where you disable the validators and the ClientValidationFunction. Debug js to see what happens.

Comment: @Tim Yes, I am trying to disable validator so just wondering why it's still active and postback never happens. There are several validators with this class and only CustomValidator remains active.

Comment: @Victor: `ControlToValidate` does not work for a CheckBoxList(see my #4).

Comment: @Tim I know that's why I cannot use it

Comment: @Victor: have a look at my js-function to disable the validators with `pain`-class that works for me. Maybe your jQuery does not work in some way.

Comment: @Victor: i have tried your code, but with my js to disable the validator and an empty validation-function which only contains `args.IsValid=false;` and it works in all browsers as expected(only for the first postback, after that it is enabled again).

Comment: strange, my validation function is above, but that shouldn't make any difference.

Comment: had to give up on using CustomValidator but implemented my own instead. But, I appreciate the effort, so I will accept